# How can I access XCom values in traditional operator that were defined in TaskFlow function?

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

I am building a dictionary of configuration parameters to pass on to another DAG via `TriggerDagRunOperator`, in a Taskflow decorated function I am building and returning said dictionary.  I need to access a key/value pair in the dictionary to fill in the field: `trigger_dag_id` in the `TriggerDagRunOperator`.  Or, I can return multiple outputs from the function that is building the dictionary.  I am having trouble coming up with a viable solution to access the `trigger_dag_id` XCom values to be used in `TriggerDagRunOperator` `trigger_dag_id` field.

```
# Assume the values in params are being passed in via conf
@task
def build_trigger_dag_config(**kwargs):
    # insert values into config
    config = {}
    config['stuff'] = kwargs['params']['stuff']
    config['trigger_dag_id'] = kwargs['params']['dag_run_id']

    # Option #1
    return config
    # Option #2
    return {'trigger_dag_config': config, 'trigger_dag_id': config['trigger_dag_id']}

trigger_dag_id_test = build_trigger_dag_config()

trigger_report_task = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="trigger_report_task",
    trigger_dag_id=<How do I access trigger_dag_id from the previous function?>
    conf=valid_input_params,
)
```

### Update

After much trial and error, it turns out there is a bug in the `TriggerDagRunOperator`.  I will post my work around ASAP.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.